# Make via Makefile fails but from command line is successful

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to build an out-of-tree module against a downloaded kernel tree.

My **Makefile** looks like this:

```
obj-m += userModule.o
ARCH := arm
CC := arm-linux-gnueabihf-
KERN_DIR := /home/user/Downloads/beaglebone-linux-5.10/
CD := /home/user/Downloads/userModule/

all:
       make ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CC) -C $(KERN_DIR) M=$(CD) modules
clean:
       make ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CC) -C $(KERN_DIR) M=$(CD) clean
help:
       make ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CC) -C $(KERN_DIR) M=$(CD) help
```

When I execute: **$make**, I get an error:

```
$make
sudo make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -C /home/user/Downloads/beaglebone-linux-5.10/ M=/home/user/Downloads/userModule/ modules
make: Entering directory '/home/user/Downloads/beaglebone-linux-5.10'
  CC [M]  /home/user/Downloads/userModule//userModule.o
/bin/sh: 1: arm-linux-gnueabihf-: not found
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:280: /home/user/Downloads/userModule//userModule.o] Error 127
make: *** [Makefile:1825: /home/user/Downloads/userModule/] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/user/Downloads/beaglebone-linux-5.10'
make: *** [Makefile:9: all] Error 2
```

But, when I comment out the entire Makefile except for the first line, so it looks like this:

```
obj-m += userModule.o
```

and I execute the same command but this time from the command line, everything is built with no error:

**$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -C /home/user/Downloads/beaglebone-linux-5.10/ M=$PWD modules**

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -C /home/user/Downloads/beaglebone-linux-5.10/ M=$PWD modules
make: Entering directory '/home/user/Downloads/beaglebone-linux-5.10'
CC [M]  /home/user/Downloads/userModule/userModule.o
MODPOST /home/user/Downloads/userModule/Module.symvers
CC [M]  /home/user/Downloads/userModule/userModule.mod.o
LD [M]  /home/user/Downloads/userModule/userModule.ko
make: Leaving directory '/home/user/Downloads/beaglebone-linux-5.10'
```

**everything goes just fine.**

I compared the 2 commands as they are shown in the building messages and they look the same.
Has anybody experienced such behavior?

Answer (score 2):

The `CC` variable is supposed to be the name of your compiler.  You have set it to the string `arm-linux-gnueabihf-` which is not the name of your compiler; in fact it's not the name of any program on your system.  So, when it is executed you get an error.

```
CC := arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

Don't set this variable.

Comment: thanks! it did fixed the issue!